# How can I make elastic APM work with AWS xray?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm

I am planning to deploy ELK to monitor my application running in AWS. My apps are using AWS xray for trace data. I am reading the doc about elastic APM to see how to ingest AWS xray to elasticsearch but I can't find any solution.

I have read the agent doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/nodejs/3.x/intro.html but xray is not listed as supported framework. Does this mean I need to build a xray agent and send the trace data to APM server? Or is there an easier way to do that?